# How to return documents based on two array elements in the document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am relatively new to Aggregation concepts in mongodb. In my documents, there is an array. I tried $match, $unwind, $group to pull a document(s) that has two given values in the array. I guess the write up is not helping .. here is the sample

Documents:

```
{Name:"Kal",    Class: "2", Subject: ["Physics", "English", "Maths"]},
{Name:"Matt",   Class: "1", Subject: ["Physics", "English"]},
{Name:"Kim",     Class: "1", Subject: ["Physics", "Spanish"]},
{Name:"Bud",    Class: "2", Subject: ["Physics", "German"]},
{Name:"Roger",  Class: "2", Subject: ["Physics", "French"]},
{Name:"Kate",   Class: "1", Subject: ["English"]}
```

from these documents, I need to pull a document that has "Class: 1" and 'Subject["Physics", "English"]'

so if I write my query (or aggregation) correctly, I should pull second document from above.

Here is what I have

```
db.Student.aggregate([{"$match": {"Class": "1",}},{"$unwind":    "$Subject"},{"$match": {"Subject": "Physics"}},{"$match": {"Subject": "English"}} ]).pretty()
```

well, the above aggregation did not get me anything back, so I tried using $and to combine both 'Physics' and 'English', but I got '$and is not a stage operator' error.

I tried this below aggregation as well, but I got nothing back.

```
db.Student.aggregate([{"$match": {"Class": "1",}},{"$match": {"Subject": ["Physics", "English"]}} ]).pretty()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the aggregation framework to do this. Simply use the `.find()` method:

If you want those documents where "Physics" and "English" are in the "Subject" array then you need to use the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator.

```js
db.Students.find( { "Subject": { "$all": [ "Physics", "English" ]  } } )
```

To return documents where only those subjects are present you need to use the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator.

```js
db.Students.find( { "Subject": { "$all": [ "Physics", "English" ]  }, "Subject": { "$size": 2 } } )
```